# The Acute Angle Between Two Tangent Lines to the Curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The parametric curve $r=(-2t^2+8t-2,cos({\pi}t),t^3-28t)$ crosses itself at one and only one point. The point is $(x,y,z)$. I found $t=-2$ to be the answer and $(x,y,z)=(-26,-1,48)$ to be the correct answer.

However it asks for the acute angle between the two tangent lines to the curve at the crossing point $cos({\Theta})=$ as well. I know what the formula will look like, but the formula implies that there will be another number, like $t=-2$, but I haven't been able to find that number? I feel like I"m done the majority of the question, but am not sure how to seal it all up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it crosses itself at one and only one point, that means that there are two values for t such that your components or r have identical values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose the trajectory crosses itself at $t = a, t = b \neq  a,$ the we have $r(a)= r(b).$  there are three simultaneous equation to solve: the first one $$-2a^2 + 8a - 2 = -2b^2 +8b -2$$ implies $b + a = 4.$ if i substitute in the $z$ component i get $$a^3 - 28a = (4-a)^3 - 28(4-a).$$ this equation has thre roots $a = -2, 2, 6$ and the corresponding $b = 6, 2, -2$. which shows that trajectory crosses itself at the point $(-26, 1, 48)$ at time $t = -2$ and again at $t = 6.$

now the tangent vector at $t$ is $(-4t + 8, -\pi\sin \pi t, 3t^2 - 28)$ evaluating this at $t = -2,$ we get $16(1,0,-1 )$ and at $t = 6$ we have $16(-1,0,5).$ the angle between these vector is $$\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{-6}{\sqrt 2\sqrt 26}\right) = 2.553 = 146.31^\circ $$

the acute angel is $33.69^\circ .$

Answer (score 0):

Confering your text,

$-2t^2 +8t - 2 = -26$

$t^2 -4t - 12 = 0$

$t = -2$ or $t = 6 \Rightarrow r(t) = (-26, +1, +48)$

$r'(t) = ...$

$u = r'(-2) = ...$

$v = r'(6) = ...$

$u \cdot v = |u| \cdot |v| \cdot cos \theta \Rightarrow \theta = ...$